# Updating ExpandableListView with notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, expandablelistview

First a short **overview** of my code, i hope its understandable:

- I have a class called `ToDoElement` with a few variables.
- I have another class called `ToDoListe` which manages the `ToDoElement`s in an ArrayList.
- `ToDoListe` contains the method `deleteElement()` to delete a `ToDoElement` from the ArrayList
- In my main activity `liste_activity` i create an object of `ToDoListe` and fill it with some Objects of `ToDoElement`.
- In the same activity i have an ExpandableListView with my own Adapter called `expListAdapter`.
- The Adapter creates the Groupviews and Childviews by getting the String variables of the `ToDoElement`s.
- I created a ContextMenu for every Group item of the list, in which i use the method `deleteElement()`.

Ok, now here is my **problem**:
After i used the method `deleteElement()` i want to update my List, because the data of the ArrayList in `ToDoListe` changed. So i call `expListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.
 But then my whole activity crashes, with the reason: "*IndexOutOfBoundException: Invalid index 4, size is 4*" (I had 5 `ToDoELement` items in my list, before deleting one of them).
I know that's because of one of my for-loops, but i don't have any idea why.

**Code fragments:**

creating new Object of ToDoListe:

```
private static ToDoListe Liste = new ToDoListe();
```

class ToDoListe (just the important methods):

```
public class ToDoListe {

     private ArrayList<ToDoElement> ToDoListe;

     public ToDoListe()
     {
         ToDoListe = new ArrayList<ToDoElement>();
     }

     public void newElement(ToDoElement element){
         ToDoListe.add(element);
     }

     public void deleteElement(int nummer) {
         ToDoListe.remove(nummer);
     }

     public int AnzahlElemente() {
         return  ToDoListe.size();
     }
}
```

define list Adapter:

```
expListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(this, createGroupList(), createChildList());
setListAdapter( expListAdapter );
```

create ArrayLists for list Adapter:

```
// creates the list with the group items
private List createGroupList() {
      ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
      for (int i=0; i < Liste.AnzahlElemente(); i++) {
        result.add(Liste.getElement(i).getUeberschrift());
      }
      return result;
    }

// creates the list with the child items
private List createChildList() {
        ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
        for(int i=0; i < Liste.AnzahlElemente(); i++) {
            ArrayList secList = new ArrayList();
            for( int n = 1 ; n <= 3 ; n++ ) {
                if (Liste.getElement(i).getStichpunkt(n).length() != 0){
                    secList.add( "- " + Liste.getElement(i).getStichpunkt(n));
                }
            }
            result.add( secList );
        }
        return result;
}
```

my own List Adapter (just the important methods):

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

private ArrayList<String> ueberschriften;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stichpunkte;

private LayoutInflater inflater;


public MyListAdapter(Context context, List _ueberschriften, List _stichpunkte) { 

        this.ueberschriften = (ArrayList)_ueberschriften;
        this.stichpunkte = (ArrayList)_stichpunkte;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_child, null);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_child_title);
        tv.setText(liste_activity.getListe().getElement(groupPosition).getStichpunkt(childPosition));

        return convertView;
    }

public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_group, null);
    }

    TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_group_title);
    tv.setText(liste_activity.getListe().getElement(groupPosition).getUeberschrift());

    return convertView;
}
```

use of notifyDataSetChanged():

```
Liste.deleteElement(groupPos);
expListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Thanks a lot for your attention!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a `DeleteMethod` of some sort to the `Adapter` and remove the item from the `Adapter` manually, not only remove it from the `List`.

Each time you refresh the the views using `notifyDataSetChanged()` the `Adapter` will call the loop around the `List`. Your `List` in the `Adapter` gets a null value due to the changes you made.

Comment: sounds good! can you give me an example, because i don't know how to write a Delete Method for an Adapter item.. ?

Comment: ok, i figured it out, it works! Here is my code for the Delete Method in my ListAdapter:
 `public void deleteItem (int nummer){`
  `stichpunkte.remove(nummer);`
  `ueberschriften.remove(nummer);`
 `}`

Comment: and this is how i use it in my main activity: `Liste.deleteElement(groupPos);` `expListAdapter.deleteItem(groupPos);` `expListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 5):

Call super in your registerDataSetObserver meke notifyDataSetChanged() working well.

```
@Override
public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
    super.registerDataSetObserver(observer);    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should call `expListAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated()`

`expListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` will just update your views for the new values for each items (no change in any of the elements)

i.e it will again call your `getChildView` and `getGroupView` for each item.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was able to resolve this error by clearing the focus of the associated `ExpandableListView` before calling `notifyDatasetChanged`