# IndexOutOfBoundException when I use notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, baseadapter

I Founded my problem in this post [Updating ExpandableListView with notifyDataSetChanged()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260409/updating-expandablelistview-with-notifydatasetchanged)

"each time you refresh the the views using setNotifyDatasetChanged the Adapter will call the loop around the List. and you List in the Adapter gets a null value due to the changes you made."

I am beginner and can not properly make changes to the list

my sources

```
public class UrlArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UrlItem> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ListView urlListView1;
    private ArrayList<UrlItem> urlItems1;

    public UrlArrayAdapter(Context context, ListView urlListView,
            ArrayList<UrlItem> urlLists) {
        super(context, urlListView.getId(), urlLists);
        this.urlItems1 = urlLists;
        this.urlListView1 = urlListView;


        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

**how do I remove an item from the list in urlLists in the base adapter??**

Comment: I decided. the decision at this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/12049357/1568164

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to overriding `public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)`, make sure your class that extends `ArrayAdapter` overrides these methods:

```
public int getCount()
public UrlItem getItem(int position)
public int getPosition(Hold item)
public long getItemId(int position)
```

I believe `notifyDataSetChanged()` will call `getCount()` on your adapter to determine how many items there are. If you don't override this method with `return urlItems1.size();` then an `IndexOutOfBoundException` seems imminent because there will be no way for your custom adapter to tell clients about its size and contents.

Comment: What should I overwrite getPosition() with?

Comment: @user2984127 A function that [returns the position of the specified item in the array](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getPosition(T)) or -1 if the item doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

To remove an item: `urlList.remove(item_index);`
Then notify that the data set has been changed.

**Based on your comment below, I'm updating my answer.**
The `remove()` method accepts the index of the element being removed, not the element itself.

So, to remove a specific number from the list you should first find its index, and then pass that index to the `remove()` method.

Ex:

```
public void deleteItem(int numberToDelete) {
    int index=-1;

    // Find the index of numberToDelete
    if(urlLists.contains(numberToDelete)){
        index = urlLists.indexOf(numberToDelete);
    }

    // Delete the number by spefying the index found.
    if(index!=-1){
        urlLists.remove(index);
    }

//...
}
```

Comment: `public void deleteItem(int nummer) {
  urlItems1.remove(nummer);
  notifyDataSetChanged();
 }` -- and it does not work

Comment: What represents your `nummer`? The number you want to delete? If so, then no, array lists does not work like this. The remove method accepts an `index` where that number is positioned in the list.

Comment: it will remove it from the list, but notifyDataSetChanged () throws an exception

Comment: Please see the link - and the answer, I think this is my situation

Comment: OK, then probably i misunderstood the question. sorry.