# notifyDataSetChanged() - IndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, indexoutofboundsexception

I do not understand what is wrong

I am use

```
  public class UrlArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {...      
         ArrayList<UrlItem> objects;

        UrlArrayAdapter(Context context, ListView urlListView,
                ArrayList<UrlItem> urlLists) {
objects = urlLists; ...



    //method
    public void deleteItem(int numberToDelete) {        
            objects.remove(numberToDelete);      
             notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

AND (the most interesting)

I get numberToDelete = 1

This line is then removed

[image]

but objects 
[image]

and when numberToDelete = 0

This line is then removed

[image]

but objects 
[image]

AND when numberToDelete = 2

objects

[image]

**but after notifyDataSetChanged(); IndexOutOfBoundException**

I already have a post ... but I can not solve this problem

[IndexOutOfBoundException when I use notifyDataSetChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990399/indexoutofboundexception-when-i-use-notifydatasetchanged)

stackoverflow.com/a/9260757/1568164 I am feeling that the situation is this, i use but not work

Then I get a position to further remove

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Planet to display
        UrlItem urlItem = (UrlItem) this.getItem(position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.database_table_item, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

            viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener1);

            viewHolder.text = (EditText) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.editText1);


            viewHolder.text
                    .setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
                        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                            int getPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();
                            if (!hasFocus) {

                                final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;
                                // urlLists
                                objects.get(getPosition).setUrl(
                                        Caption.getText().toString());
                            } else {

                                DatabaseTable.setPosition(getPosition); // This is a future for "numberToDelete"
                            }
                        }
                    });

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.checkBox1, viewHolder.checkbox);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.editText1, viewHolder.text);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }
        viewHolder.text.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.text.setText(urlItem.getUrl());
        viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(urlItem.getUse());

        return convertView;

    }
```

My basis Activity where I call the removal line

```
public class DatabaseTable extends Activity {
    private Settings setting;
    private ArrayList<UrlItem> urlLists;
    private ListAdapter uAdapter;
    private ListView urlListView;
    static int position;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.database_table_list);
        LBD conection = new LBD(this);
        conection.open();
        setting = conection.tblSettings();
        setting.create();
        urlLists = setting.selectRssTable();
        urlListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        uAdapter = new UrlArrayAdapter(DatabaseTable.this, urlListView,
                urlLists);
        urlListView.setAdapter(uAdapter);
        urlListView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
}
    public static void setPosition(int pos) {
        position = pos;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, 2, "Delete URL");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 2:
        ((UrlArrayAdapter) uAdapter).deleteItem(position); 
break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

continuing the theme
I experimented and concluded that the strings in the list of adapters have little to do with the fact that the output to the screen, so the challenge is changing. need to understand how to delete rows from the screen

Comment: can you add the code to your question where when you choose an object from the table you return the index of that object?

Comment: what is `int position`, is this the index of the chosen UrlItem?

Comment: and just out of interest, when you select URL_3, what index is position set to?

Comment: Well of course it is also seen on the pictures

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9260757/1568164 I am feeling that the situation is this but not work

Comment: Imagine that there is a class and two methods - I showed them. but in notifyDataSetChanged () something happens in the BaseAdapter is partially described [link] stackoverflow.com/a/9260757/1568164

Comment: In your `optionItemSelected()` have you tried `urlLists.remove(position); uAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` ?? Remove   `deleteItem(int numberToDelete)` from BaseAdapter Class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution was simple.

```
viewHolder.text
                    .setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
                        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
```

did not work properly, redraw the list of focus has changed and deleted lines chaotic .. agonized for a week a decision was simple, left to fix